# how to get a breakout made for module that doesn't have one?

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, pcb-assembly, breakout

I'm just starting out in this field and I got ideas for projects I want to build but I'm running into problems,  not so much with how to find the part I want or how to get it to work. but how to physically connect it. I see modules like this [image: surface mount module]

and while I can find information on what pins I need to hook up what to, so the thing does what I want. I'm no where even close to being good enough as soldering to attach wires to modules like this. And most of the time I can't find an existing breakout board for the module I want to use. sometimes I can find one for other modules that claim to have similar functions but when I start reading though the details I find it really only shares the features I wasn't planning on using while the ones I did want aren't available.

So all that is me explaining why I need to ask is there service or something that I could use where I can get the module I want on a board? I don't mind having to either buy the module separately and sending it to them and then paying them to assemble the board.  or buying the module through them and paying extra for assembly. Or is there some trick to making them myself that I haven't heard about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, yes there are services like that.  Places like SeeedStudio will allow you to design a PCB and get it printed, then you can choose from a list of 500 parts they have or you can send them your part and they will solder.  There are many other places like this, but this was the first I thought of.  Heres a link since their site it a little difficult to navigate: http://www.seeedstudio.com/service/index.php?r=pcb

You should note that this could end up being pretty expensive.  I'd say that the better bet (at least long term) is for you to learn to solder them.  Find old soldering boards or design your own and just practice a bunch until you feel confident doing it for production work.  Another option would be to find a nearby university and see if they have an EE club or robotics club and ask if anybody there can solder well.  You could probably pay them with pizza and/or beer and everybody would be happy.

Comment: +1 this. You _really_ should learn to solder. It'll serve you throughout your career (and hobbies). And the best way to learn is to have someone give you a 5-minute intro, then do lots of practice on your own!

Comment: I get what your saying and I do plan on working on getting better at it. but there are some projects that have a few of these tricky bits in them that I'd really rather get done sooner. then latter after I've worked up my soldering skills to that level.

Comment: For reference: I also want to throw out MacroFab as a possibility since they can work with lower numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For (small batch) production, these modules can be soldered on other PCBs, all you need is SMD pads in the right places, slightly elongated if you want to hand solder.

For development, there is usually a development kit available from the module manufacturer.

Comment: Those Dev kits are a no go.  the modules I'm looking at average $30 and the Dev kits are $200-$400 plus they have all these extra parts I don't need on them. I like mwwalk's answer looks like they charge $10 for the board, so even if they charged like $90 for the assembly, I'd still be getting what I need for much cheaper then the dev kit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free software to create a board with the pads you need, pretty simply by selecting the package type. Then drag solder.

You can download the gerber file after building it and send it to a number of companies to have it manufactured, for probably $20

[123d.circuits](https://123d.circuits.io)